# Distributing work among cupboards

Tags: probability

I am self studying, and have the answer to this question at the back of the book. The question is as follows (paraphrase):

> A survey of chemical research workers has shown on average that each man requires no cupboard $60\%$ of the time, one cupboard $30\%$ of the time and two cupboards $10\%$ of the time; three or more were never needed. If four chemists work independently, how many cupboards should be provided so that there are adequate facilities at least $95\%$ of the time?

The answer is that $4$ cupboards are enough for $95.85\%$ of the time. I just do not know how to get the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a$ be the time when a person needs no cupboard, $b$ when he needs $1$, and $c$ when he needs $2$. These are the possible situations when there is enough cupboard space:

$$
\begin{array}{cccccc}
&aaaa\\
&baaa&abaa&aaba&aaab\\
&bbaa&baba&baab&abba&abab&aabb\\
&caaa&acaa&aaca&aaac
\end{array}
$$

Then we simply add the probabilities of each of these situations happening:

$$
\begin{align}
    &[60\%\cdot 60\%\cdot 60\%*60\%]\\
    +4\cdot &[60\%\cdot 60\%\cdot 60\%\cdot 30\%]\\
    +6\cdot &[60\%\cdot 60\%\cdot 30\%\cdot 30\%]\\
    +4\cdot &[60\%\cdot 60\%\cdot 60\%\cdot 10\%]
\end{align}
$$

which comes out to be $95.85\%$.